# Calculating the integral of a step function.

Tags: analysis

I can solve the first half of a question:

Explain what the indicator function $χ_I$ for a given interval $I$ is.

That is:

If $A \subset \Bbb R$ is a subset then the indicator function $χ_A$ of A is defined as:

$χ_A(x):=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \in A$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \notin A$}
\end{cases}$

But I am stuck on this latter part of the question:

Then compute the integral of the step function $3χ_{[0,2]} − 2χ_{(0,3]} + χ_{[−1,1]}$.

Any hints on where to begin would be helpful.

Comment: Are you required to compute a definite integral? If yes, then what are the limits of the definite integral?

Comment: The question literally just asks to calculate its integral. No limits are given. Surely, as the function has the range for each step in the function, the integral here will be over the range, $[-1,3]$?

Comment: Yea, the integral is zero outside of that range. You can use the linearity of the integral to calculate the individual pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=3\chi_{[0,2]}(x) − 2\chi_{(0,3]}(x) + \chi_{[−1,1]}(x)$ . Also, consider the integral with lower and upper limits $l$ and $u$ respectively, where $l,u\in\Bbb R$. Then,

$$\int\limits_l^uf(x)\,\mathrm dx=3\int\limits_u^l\chi_{[0,2]}(x)\,\mathrm dx-2\int\limits_u^l\chi_{(0,3]}(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int\limits_u^l\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Because the indicator function is a constant function (zero function) outside the specified subset, we can just ignore those parts since those integral parts just give $0$. Also, those indicator functions simply give a constant value for their specified subset, so it's a constant function $(x\mapsto 1)$ for those subsets. Hence, we have,

$$\int\limits_l^uf(x)\,\mathrm dx=3\int\limits_0^2\mathrm dx-2\int\limits_0^3\mathrm dx+\int\limits_{-1}^1\mathrm dx$$

Can you do this part yourself?

Comment: That is extremely helpful. I can work from here now, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a suitable set $A$, we have
$m(A) = \int 1_A$, that is, the volume of the set is given by integrating the indicator function.

If $A$ is an interval $[a,b]$, then we have $\int 1_A = \int_a^b 1 = b-a$.

Since the integral is linear, we have
$\int \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{I_k} = \sum_k \alpha_k \int 1_{I_k} = \sum_k \alpha_k m({I_k})$.